# QThread doesn't appear to start; PyQt5, Python 2.7.9

Tags: pyqt5

**SUMMARY**
PyQt5 doesn't appear to be creating a new thread corresponding to QThread object, or I haven't established Slot/Signal linkage correctly.  Please help me to isolate my problem.

---

I'm a relatively casual user of Python, but I've been asked to create a utility for another team that wraps some of their Python libraries (which themselves wrap C++) in a GUI.  Because this utility is for another team, I can't change versions of compilers etc, or at least, not without providing a decent reason.
The utility is intended to provide an interface for debugging into some hardware that my colleagues are developing.

After examining the options, I decided to use Qt and the PyQt bindings.  The steps I followed were:

1. Install Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (required because other team's libraries are compiled using this version of the MS compiler).
2. Install Python 2.7.9 (their version of Python)
3. Install qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2010-5.2.1.exe
4. Get source for SIP-4.18.zip and compile and install
5. Get source for PyQt-gpl-5.2.1.zip, compile and install
6. Try to build a PyQt application that wraps the other team's comms and translation libraries.  Those libraries aren't asynchronous as far as I can tell, so I think that I need to separate that part of the application from the GUI.

The code that I've written produces the UI and is responsive in the sense that if I put break points in the methods that are called from the QAction objects, then those break points are appropriately triggered.  My problem is that the Worker object that I create doesn't appear to move to a separate thread, (despite the call to moveToThread) because if I make the connection of type BlockingQueuedConnection instead of QueuedConnection then I get a deadlock. Breakpoints that I put on the slots in the Worker type are never triggered.

Here's the code::

```
import os
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QApplication, QStatusBar, QLabel, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot


class Worker(QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self._isRunning = True
        self._connectionId = ""
        self._terminate = False

    @pyqtSlot()
    def cmd_start_running(self):
        """This slot is used to send a command to the HW asking for it to enter Running mode.
        It will actually work by putting a command in a queue for the main_loop to get to
        in its own serialised good time.  All the other commands will work in a similar fashion
        Up until such time as it is implemented, I will fake it."""
        self._isRunning = True
        pass

    @pyqtSlot()
    def cmd_stop_running(self):
        """This slot is used to send a command to the HW asking for it to enter Standby mode.
        Up until such time as it is implemented, I will fake it."""
        self._isRunning = False

    @pyqtSlot()
    def cmd_get_version(self):
        """This slot is used to send a command to the HW asking for its version string"""
        pass

    @pyqtSlot()
    def cmd_terminate(self):
        """This slot is used to notify this object that it has to join the main thread."""
        pass

    @pyqtSlot()
    def main_loop(self):
        """This slot is the main loop that is attached to the QThread object.  It has sleep periods
        that allow the messages on the other slots to be processed."""
        while not self._terminate:
            self.thread().sleep(1)
            # While there is stuff on the wire, get it off, translate it, then
            # signal it
            # For the mean while, pretend that _isRunning corresponds to when
            # RT streams will be
            # being received from the HW.
            if self._isRunning:
                pass
            # Search queue for commands, if any found, translate, then put on
            # the wire

class DemoMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    sgnl_get_version = pyqtSignal()
    sgnl_start_running = pyqtSignal()
    sgnl_stop_running = pyqtSignal()
    sgnl_terminate = pyqtSignal()


    def __init__(self):
        super(DemoMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

        self._workerObject = Worker()
        self._workerThread = QThread()
        self._workerObject.moveToThread(self._workerThread)
        self._workerThread.started.connect(self._workerObject.main_loop, type=Qt.QueuedConnection)


        # I changed the following connection to type BlockingQueuedConnection,
        # and got a Deadlock error
        # reported, so I assume that there is already a problem before I get to
        # this point.
        # I understand that the default for 'type' (Qt.AutoConnection) is
        # supposed to correctly infer that a QueuedConnection is required.
        # I was getting desperate.
        self.sgnl_get_version.connect(self._workerObject.cmd_get_version, type=Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.sgnl_start_running.connect(self._workerObject.cmd_start_running, type=Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.sgnl_stop_running.connect(self._workerObject.cmd_stop_running, type=Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.sgnl_terminate.connect(self._workerObject.cmd_terminate, type=Qt.QueuedConnection)



    def initUI(self):

        textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(textEdit)
        lbl = QLabel(self.statusBar())
        lbl.setText("HW Version:   ")
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(lbl)

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit24.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        connectAction = QAction(QIcon('connect24.png'), 'Connect', self)
        connectAction.setStatusTip('Connect to HW')
        connectAction.triggered.connect(self.establishCanConnection)

        enterRunningAction = QAction(QIcon('start24.png'), 'Start Running', self)
        enterRunningAction.setStatusTip('Start Running')
        enterRunningAction.triggered.connect(self.enterRunning)

        enterStandbyAction = QAction(QIcon('stop24.png'), 'Stop Running', self)
        enterStandbyAction.setStatusTip('Stop Running')
        enterStandbyAction.triggered.connect(self.enterStandby)

        self.statusBar()

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
        hwMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Hardware')
        hwMenu.addAction(connectAction)
        hwMenu.addAction(enterRunningAction)
        hwMenu.addAction(enterStandbyAction)

        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        toolbar.addAction(exitAction)
        toolbar.addAction(connectAction)
        toolbar.addAction(enterRunningAction)
        toolbar.addAction(enterStandbyAction)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 350) # x, y, width, height
        self.setWindowTitle('Demo Prog')
        self.show()

    def establishCanConnection(self):
        iDlg = QInputDialog(self)
        iDlg.setInputMode(QInputDialog.IntInput)
        idInt, ok = iDlg.getInt(self, 'CAN ID Selection', 'HW ID:')
        canID = '%s%d' % ('HW', idInt)
        if ok:
            self._workerThread.start()
            pass
        # this would be where the channel is established

    def enterRunning(self):
        self.sgnl_start_running.emit()
        # this would be where the command to start running is sent from

    def enterStandby(self):
        self.sgnl_stop_running.emit()
        # send the command to stop running


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = DemoMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that the call to start the _workerThread is in the establishCanConnection method, but that shouldn't be a problem, should it?
I used the procmon utility to check if more threads are created if establishCanConnection is run, and it appears that there are more threads, but I found it hard to relate which thread (if any of them) related to the QThread object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `BlockingQueuedConnection` unless you really need it. If you don't know whether you need it or not, then you don't need it.

Cross-thread signals are queued in the event-loop of the receiving thread. If that thread is running code that blocks, it won't be able to process any events. Thus, if you send a signal with `BlockingQueuedConnection` to a thread that is blocked, you'll get a deadlock.

Your example uses a worker object that runs a blocking while loop, so it is subject to the deadlock problem outlined above. If you want to send signals to a thread that is blocked, you will need to arrange for the blocking code to periodically allow the thread to process its events, like this:

```
    while not self._terminate:
        self.thread().sleep(1)
        QApplication.processEvents()
```

PS:

If you want to check that the worker is running in a different thread, you can print the return value of `QThread.currentThread()` or `QThread.currentThreadId()` (these functions are static, so you don't need an instance of `QThread` to call them).

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer.  In my question I didn't really want to focus on the BlockingQueuedConnection - that was an experiment that I thought added weight to the idea that the worker object wasn't really on the worker thread.  I was wrong about that.  The other two things that I got from this answer are 1) QApplication.processEvents() (which is what "unblocked" me), and 2) the added bonus of QThread.currentThreadId().  Thank you.